# Library to detect memory leak in android using Kotlin

Tags: android, memory-leaks, kotlin

I'm using Leak Canary to prevent *memory leaks* in Android...using Kotlin, this library still works? There is another for Kotlin?

Leak Canary can detect, based on source code (*i am right?*) and with **head dumbs**, the reference of context passed from activity/fragmento to *Async* class' constructors, and in case when *WeakReferences* are not used properly whenever the user leaves an activity when the *Async* does not finish its process, the LeakCanary detect a memory leak.
How its works for Kotlin?

Leak Canary is based on (its analyses) generated *bytecode* and there is **real** no difference between using either Java code or Kolin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Leak Canary does not generate any bytecode. It uses Java's `Reference` and `ReferenceQueue` objects to track objects when they are supposed to be garbage-collected and generating a report if the object is still alive after a timeout,

In short, Leak Canary will work as expected for any language that is based on Java Bytecode. (If native code gets involved it will probably become less clear)